# Text bind:value is not working according to Select bindings

Tags: data-binding, svelte

I need to input the value which i got it from selected option. If I select Tokyo, I need to input the code 1850147(CityCode of Tokyo) via bind:value. But my code didn't work that way. Help me fix this..

```
<script>
  
  let cities = [
    {
      CityCode: "1248991",
      CityName: "Colombo",
      Temp: "33.0",
      Status: "Clouds",
    },
    {
      CityCode: "1850147",
      CityName: "Tokyo",
      Temp: "8.6",
      Status: "Clear",
    },
    {
      CityCode: "2644210",
      CityName: "Liverpool",
      Temp: "16.5",
      Status: "Rain",
    },
    {
      CityCode: "2988507",
      CityName: "Paris",
      Temp: "22.4",
      Status: "Clear",
    },
    {
      CityCode: "2147714",
      CityName: "Sydney",
      Temp: "27.3",
      Status: "Rain",
    },
    {
      CityCode: "4930956",
      CityName: "Boston",
      Temp: "4.2",
      Status: "Mist",
    },
    {
      CityCode: "1796236",
      CityName: "Shanghai",
      Temp: "10.1",
      Status: "Clouds",
    },
    {
      CityCode: "3143244",
      CityName: "Oslo",
      Temp: "-3.9",
      Status: "Clear",
    },
  ];

  let selected;

  function handleSubmit() {
    alert(
      `Chosen city ${selected.CityCode}`
    );

  }

</script>

<h2>Choose City from here</h2>

<form on:submit|preventDefault={handleSubmit}>
  <select bind:value={selected}>
    {#each cities as city}
      <option value={city}>
        {city.CityName}
      </option>
    {/each}
  </select>

  <button type="submit"> Submit </button>

  
</form>

<input type="text" bind:value={selected.CityCode}>
```

When I select an option and hit the submit button, It was correctly shown on alert but input type has not been changed according to what I selected previously... What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't quite tell what you're trying to accomplish because binding a value in two different places will become hard to work with. Binding means two-way updates. You're binding to `selected`, which is a variable (great!), but then you are also binding to `selected.CityCode` which is not a variable. If you want to just pass the value, you can do

```html
<input type="text" value={selected.CityCode}>
```

If you still want the input to be bound, you can pass the value as you submit, like so:

```html
<script>
  let cities = [
    {
      CityCode: "1248991",
      CityName: "Colombo",
      Temp: "33.0",
      Status: "Clouds",
    },
    {
      CityCode: "1850147",
      CityName: "Tokyo",
      Temp: "8.6",
      Status: "Clear",
    },
    {
      CityCode: "2644210",
      CityName: "Liverpool",
      Temp: "16.5",
      Status: "Rain",
    },
    {
      CityCode: "2988507",
      CityName: "Paris",
      Temp: "22.4",
      Status: "Clear",
    },
    {
      CityCode: "2147714",
      CityName: "Sydney",
      Temp: "27.3",
      Status: "Rain",
    },
    {
      CityCode: "4930956",
      CityName: "Boston",
      Temp: "4.2",
      Status: "Mist",
    },
    {
      CityCode: "1796236",
      CityName: "Shanghai",
      Temp: "10.1",
      Status: "Clouds",
    },
    {
      CityCode: "3143244",
      CityName: "Oslo",
      Temp: "-3.9",
      Status: "Clear",
    },
  ];

  let selected;
  let input;

  function handleSubmit() {
    alert(`Chosen city ${selected.CityCode}`);
    input = selected.CityCode;
  }
</script>

<h2>Choose City from here</h2>

<form on:submit|preventDefault={handleSubmit}>
  <select bind:value={selected}>
    {#each cities as city}
      <option value={city}>
        {city.CityName}
      </option>
    {/each}
  </select>

  <button type="submit"> Submit </button>

  
</form>

<input type="text" bind:value={input}>
```